# При использовании multiprocessing идёт зацикливание после компиляции pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, multiprocessing

Я использую multiprocessing и столкнулся с проблемой. После компиляции программы в exe с помощью pyinstaller, почему-то всё начиная с `print('123')` зацикливается.

Когда я запускаю не скомпилированный скрипт, то всё работает нормально.

```py
import multiprocessing

def main():
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=main)
    main_process.start()
    print('123')
```

Comment: Винда? Попробуйте добавить `freeze_support()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support Хотя может и не в этом дело.

Comment: Вы можете продемонстрировать своё высказывание - "почему-то всё начиная с print('123') зацикливается."

Comment: Я добавил ```freeze_support()``` и это помогло. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Единственное что приходит на ум, что вопрос был - почему скрипт не прерывается после `print('123')`, если мы не делали `main_process.join()`.

Ответ - потому, что есть аргумент [daemon](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocess#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) который по умолчанию False.

Чтобы скрипт прервался, он должен быть True - `multiprocessing.Process(target=main, daemon=True)`

Comment: Это не то, что я хотел, но зацикливание ушло. Спасибо.

Comment: Под вопросом написали добавить ```freeze_support()``` и это помогло.